# A simple problem in two dimensional optimization

Tags: optimization

I have the following problem:
given
$$f_1=\frac{-12d_1}{\pi d_2-12}$$
and:
$$f_2=\frac{\pi d_1d_2}{\pi(d_1+d_2)-12}$$
I need to find the maximum of the following function:
$$F(d_1,d_2)=|f_1|+|f_2|$$
with the following constrains:
$$|f_1|\ge a$$
$$|f_2|\ge b$$
Thanks in advance.